# Windows Phone 7 SDK and Visual Studio 2010 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Hmmm, wonder if I have the first VS 2010 RTM question? Anyway..

Installing the Windows Phone 7 SDK I get the following error

```
Incompatible Products
VC 10.0 Runtime
.NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack
Microsoft.NET Framework 4 Client Profile
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended
```

This was reported as an issue with Beta 2 and the fix was to install the RC. Anyone know why it's incompatible with the RTM? Will we have to wait for an update to the SDK?

Regards,

Alex..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because Windows Phone 7 dev is incompatible with the VS 2010 RTM. I just made the same upsetting discovery.

You can register to be emailed when they release a compatible one [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/cmpn/vslaunch/default.mspx)

Official story [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wpdev/archive/2010/04/12/visual-studio-2010-rtm-and-the-windows-phone-developer-tools-ctp.aspx).

Comment: Man that sucks and the site you linked gives a 500 when I try to register..
Cheers though!

Comment: Annoying isn't it anybody tried with the Express editions yet? It's unclear whether it's just an issue with the full version or not

Comment: I installed the Visual Studio 2010 Express before finding this out myself. Installing a Virtual Machine to run VS 2010 on while keeping the VS 2010 for Windows Phone CTP on physical machine works for me. Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone is built with a non-RTM version of Visual Studio 2010 which is why they are not compatible. Some more updates are coming in May, information wise, so this may indicate that a Visual Studio 2010 Express RTM release will come then also.

Answer (score 5):

I am the Director of Developer Experience on Windows Phone 7.  This error is in fact an issue with customers who have installed VS2010 RTM.  If you haven't installed VS2010 RTM, you are unaffected.  Once you install VS2010 RTM, you cannot install the Express SKU of the Phone tools.

We should have a refresh of the Windows Phone Developer Tools shortly which will fix this issue, as well as add a few updates.  I will update this answer when we post the updated tools, but should anyone have questions, I am on twitter @brandonwatson.

UPDATE: the tools are live - if you have final build of VS2010, go here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cabcd5ed-7dfc-4731-9d7e-3220603cad14

Comment: Hi Brandon

Thanks so much for your reply, however I wiped and reinstalled my machine on the day of RTM so I got the above error on a machine that never saw the RC?

Alex..

Comment: Alex, can you walk me through your install process?  Did you wipe, and then install VS2010, or try to install Windows Phone Dev tools on a machine that had was newly wiped and had never seen VS2010?

Comment: Can not install, it keeps tellinf me that Microsoft Phone Developer Tools must be removed. An this does not appear in add/remove programs.

Comment: the link is now dead. Seriously, how about Microsoft create  a URI like *microsoft.com/windowsphone7/sdk*. I've been searching for the SDK for 5 minutes already.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Visual Studio 2010 version you have:

- Visual Studio 2010 RTM:
  install [Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13890) followed by the [Windows Phone Developer Tools January 2011 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23854) and develop for Windows Phone 7
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1:
  install [Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.1 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11321) and develop for Windows Phone 7.0 or 7.1

Until Microsoft kills the above links too ;-)